# Remove borders from Kendo Grid

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid that has a toolbar and pager and I am trying to remove the borders from the grid that are associated with those items.  So I only want the border to be around the grid itself, from the top of the column headers to the bottom of the grid where the scrollbar ends.  Could someone provide some advice or an example on how to do that?

jsfiddle.net/S6d7M/39/
So when I do this, I want to still have left and right borders only on the grid content so that the top buttons and the bottom pager stuff is not surrounded by a border.

Comment: Best way is to use the selector element in your dev tools, select your item. Should give you class to change for CSS. For example. I've done input.k-textbox { color: #FFFFFF !important; } for editable input text. If you fiddle your code I can help you more on this.

Answer (score 0):

For removing borders around the header define the following CSS style

```
#grid thead th {
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Which borders do you want to remove around the pager?

Try with:

```
#grid .k-grid-pager, #grid .k-grid-header {
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: If you look at this fiddle, you can see that the left border extends into the header and pager http://jsfiddle.net/S6d7M/39/

Comment: Right! You did not define `border-left` as 0.

Comment: I was just doing that to show you how it comes out.  If you set border-left to 0 then there will be no line at all on the left side.  I still want a line from the column header to the last row of the grid.

Comment: try adding `.k-grid-header .k-header:first-child {
border-left-width: 1px;
}`

Comment: Ok. That works for the left side of the header.  I was able to get the grid rows with the same concept.  Do you know how to get the border on the right side of the header and grid?  I think it would have to do with the scrollbar.